# Autofac retry logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I have an ASP.NET application which utilizes a `SingleInstance()` service client (connects to cluster over a VNET), on application start I have a 5 second delay/retry/delay/retry loop to initialize the service, but once it's initialized autofac takes my service client and runs with it.

My question is, if my service client loses its connection over the VNET, how can I force Autofac to reuse my initialization logic? Is this possible to do in an idiomatic autofac-ey way?

Here's the initialization code:

```
builder.Register(c => ClusterClient.Initialize(timeout: 5/*seconds*/)).SingleInstance();
```

Comment: *if my service client loses its connection over the VNET, how can I force Autofac to reuse my initialization logic?* - How can we tell you that when we have no idea what your initialization logic *is* or how it works? It is not even clear how application composition has anything remotely to do with the *runtime behavior* of connecting to a network.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I already said what the initialization does; it a 5 second delay/retry/delay/retry loop. The point isnt how its implemented, the point is that I want to invalidate the resource contained in the DI container so that it has to re-run the initialization process if the connection is lost

Answer (score 0):

First, whatever it is that `ClusterClient.Initialize()` returns, you're configuring Autofac to resolve a dependency on that specific class, which means that some class has a hard dependency on whatever that type is.

To work around this I'd do the following:

1. Define an interface that describes whatever your class is going to do with this object.
2. Create a "wrapper" class that implements that interface. That class can internally call `ClusterClient.Initialize()` and manage an internal instance of whatever that method returns. That class can also handle the retry logic.
3. Whatever class previously depended on whatever `ClusterClient.Initialize()` returns, modify it to depend on your new interface.
4. Register the wrapper class with Autofac as the implementation of your interface.

Now your class depends on an abstraction and your container doesn't have to be concerned with retry logic.

As for the retry logic itself, [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry) is a Nuget package that makes it easy to define a retry policy.